# Checking if Frequentist approach is correct? Bayesian approach using MCMC for AB test. How to calculate Bayes Factors in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, ab-testing, hypothesis-test

I've been trying to get my head around Frequentist and Bayesian approaches for a toy data AB test problem.

The results don't really make sense to me. I am struggling to understand the results, or whether I have computed them (in)correctly (which is probably likely). Furthermore, after much research, I am still somewhat lost as to how to compute Bayes Factors. I've seen packages in R that make this look somewhat easy. Alas, I am not familiar with R and would prefer to be able to solve this problem in Python.

I would greatly appreciate any help and guidance regarding this!

Here is the data:

```
# imports
import pingouin as pg
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as scs
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# A = control -- B = treatment
a_success = 10730
a_failure = 61988
a_total = a_success + a_failure
a_cr = a_success / a_total

b_success = 10966
b_failure = 60738
b_total = b_success + b_failure
b_cr = b_success / b_total
```

I started by doing some power analysis, to determine the number of required samples with a power of 0.8, alpha of 0.05 and a practical significance of 2%. I'm not sure whether expected conversion rates should be supplied, or the baseline + some proportion. Depending on the effect size, the required number of samples increases significantly.

```
# determine required sample size 
baseline_rate = a_cr
practical_significance = 0.02
alpha = 0.05
power = 0.8 
nobs1 = None

# is this how to calculate effect size?
effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(baseline_rate, baseline_rate + practical_significance) # 5204

# # or this?
# effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(baseline_rate, baseline_rate + baseline_rate * practical_significance) # 228583

sample_size = sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(effect_size = effect_size, 
                                               power = power, 
                                               alpha = alpha,
                                               nobs1 = nobs1,
                                               ratio = 1)
```

I continued trying to determine if the null hypothesis could be rejected:

```
# calculate pooled probability
pooled_probability = (a_success + b_success) / (a_total + b_total)

# calculate pooled standard error and margin of error
se_pooled = math.sqrt(pooled_probability * (1 - pooled_probability) * (1 / b_total + 1 / a_total))
z_score = scs.norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2)
margin_of_error = se_pooled * z_score

# the estimated difference between probability of conversions of both groups
d_hat = (test_b_success / test_b_total) - (test_a_success / test_a_total)

# test if null hypothesis can be rejected
lower_bound = d_hat - margin_of_error
upper_bound = d_hat + margin_of_error

if practical_significance < lower_bound:
    print("reject null hypothesis -- groups do not have the same conversion rates")
else: 
    print("do not reject the null hypothesis -- groups have the same conversion rates")
```

which evaluates to 'do not reject the null ...' despite group B (treatment) showing a 3.65% relative improvement with regards to conversion rate over group A (control) which seems... odd?

I tried a slightly different approach (I guess a slightly different hypothesis?):

```
successes = [a_success, b_success]
nobs = [a_total, b_total]

z_stat, p_value = sms.proportions_ztest(successes, nobs=nobs)
(lower_a, lower_b), (upper_a, upper_b) = sms.proportion_confint(successes, nobs=nobs, alpha=alpha)

if p_value < alpha:
    print("reject null hypothesis -- groups do not have the same conversion rates")
else: 
    print("do not reject the null hypothesis -- groups have the same conversion rates")
```

Which evaluates to 'reject null hypothesis ... ' with p-value: 0.004236. This seems highly contradictory, especially since the p-value is < 0.01.

On to Bayes... I created some arrays of success and failures (and only tested on 100 observations) due to how long this thing takes, and ran the following:

```
# generate lists of 1, 0
obs_a = np.repeat([1, 0], [a_success, a_failure]) 
obs_v = np.repeat([1, 0], [b_success, b_failure])

for _ in range(10):
    np.random.shuffle(observations_A)
    np.random.shuffle(observations_B)

with pm.Model() as model:
    p_A = pm.Beta("p_A", 1, 1)
    p_B = pm.Beta("p_B", 1, 1)
    
    delta = pm.Deterministic("delta", p_A - p_B)

    obs_A = pm.Bernoulli("obs_A", p_A, observed = obs_a[:1000])
    obs_B = pm.Bernoulli("obs_B", p_B, observed = obs_b[:1000])
    
    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step = step, chains = 2)
```

Firstly, I understand that you are supposed to burn some proportion of the trace -- how do you determine an appropriate number of indices to burn?

In trying to evaluate the posterior probabilities, is the following code the correct way to do this?

```
b_lift = (trace['p_B'].mean() - trace['p_A'].mean()) / trace['p_A'].mean() * 100
b_prob = np.mean(trace["delta"] > 0)

a_lift = (trace['p_A'].mean() - trace['p_B'].mean()) / trace['p_B'].mean() * 100
a_prob = np.mean(trace["delta"] < 0)

# is the Bayes Factor just the ratio of the posterior probabilities for these two models?
BF = (trace['p_B'] / trace['p_A']).mean()

print(f'There is {b_prob} probability B outperforms A by a magnitude of {round(b_lift, 2)}%') 
print(f'There is {a_prob} probability A outperforms B by a magnitude of {round(a_lift, 2)}%') 
print('BF:', BF)
-- output:
There is 0.666 probability B outperforms A by a magnitude of 1.29%
There is 0.334 probability A outperforms B by a magnitude of -1.28%
BF: 1.013357654428127
```

I suspect that this is not the correct way to calculate Bayes Factors. How can the Bayes Factor be calculated?

I really hope you can help me understand all of the above... I realize it's an exceptionally long post. But I've tried every resource I can find and am still stuck!

Kind regards.